# Spark: How to filter out data based on subset condition

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have two table, p_to_v mapping, g_to_v mapping.

```
scala> val p_to_v = Seq(("p1", "v1"), ("p1", "v2"), ("p2", "v1")).toDF("p", "v")
scala> p_to_v.show
+---+---+
|  p|  v|
+---+---+
| p1| v1|
| p1| v2|
| p2| v1|
+---+---+
```

"p1" is mapped to [v1, v2]

"p2" is mapped to [v1]

```
scala> val g_to_v = Seq(("g1", "v1"), ("g2", "v1"), ("g2", "v2"), ("g3", "v2")).toDF("g", "v")
scala> g_to_v.show
+---+---+
|  g|  v|
+---+---+
| g1| v1|
| g2| v1|
| g2| v2|
| g3| v2|
+---+---+
```

"g1" is mapped to [v1]

"g2" is mapped to [v1,v2]

"g3" is mapped to [v2]

I want to get all *p* and *g* combination for which corresponding *v* mapping of p is subset of *v* mapping of *g*

```
p1 [v1, v2] - g2 [v1, v2]
p2 [v1] - g1 [v1]
p2 [v1] - g2 [v1, v2]
```

How can I get same?

Comment: can you add how you want to see the output

Comment: i don't see "g3" in your example output

Comment: g3 is linked with [v2] and there is no p for which its corresponding v is subset of [v2]

Comment: @SarathChandraVema I just need g and p, so dataframe with g and p as column is sufficient

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is pretty straightforward. You need to use groupBy & then simple inner join

```
scala> val p_to_v = Seq(("p1", "v1"), ("p1", "v2"), ("p2", "v1")).toDF("p", "v")
19/10/16 22:11:55 WARN metastore: Failed to connect to the MetaStore Server...
p_to_v: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [p: string, v: string]

scala> val g_to_v = Seq(("g1", "v1"), ("g2", "v1"), ("g2", "v2"), ("g3", "v2")).toDF("g", "v")
g_to_v: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [g: string, v: string]
```

Now do groupBy operation

```
scala> val pv = p_to_v.groupBy($"p").agg(collect_list("v").as("pv"))
pv: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = pv = [p: string, pv: array<string>]

scala> val gv = g_to_v.groupBy($"g").agg(collect_list("v").as("gv"))
gv: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [g: string, gv: array<string>]

scala> pv.show
+---+--------+
|  p|      pv|
+---+--------+
| p2|    [v1]|
| p1|[v1, v2]|
+---+--------+

scala> gv.show
+---+--------+
|  g|      gv|
+---+--------+
| g2|[v2, v1]|
| g3|    [v2]|
| g1|    [v1]|
+---+--------+
```

Create an UDF for finding the subset

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

def subLis(ar1: Seq[Row], ar2: Seq[Row]) = ar1.toSet.subsetOf(ar2.toSet)
    subLis: (ar1: Seq[org.apache.spark.sql.Row], ar2: Seq[org.apache.spark.sql.Row])Boolean

val subLisUDF = udf(subLis _)
    UserDefinedFunction(<function2>,BooleanType,None)
```

Now you can perform a cross join & apply the UDF

```
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.crossJoin.enabled", "true")
pv.join(gv).withColumn("newdsa", subLisUDF($"pv", $"gv")).filter($"newdsa").show

+---+--------+---+--------+------+
|  p|      pv|  g|      gv|newdsa|
+---+--------+---+--------+------+
| p2|    [v1]| g2|[v2, v1]|  true|
| p1|[v1, v2]| g2|[v2, v1]|  true|
| p2|    [v1]| g1|    [v1]|  true|
+---+--------+---+--------+------+
```

Or joins with condition

```
pv.join(gv, pv("pv") === gv("gv") || subLisUDF($"pv", $"gv")).show

+---+--------+---+--------+
|  p|      pv|  g|      gv|
+---+--------+---+--------+
| p2|    [v1]| g2|[v1, v2]|
| p1|[v1, v2]| g2|[v1, v2]|
| p2|    [v1]| g1|    [v1]|
+---+--------+---+--------+
```

Try both and take the best performing one.

Comment: please mark this as answer, if this resolves your query

Comment: Thanks for reply. p2 and g2 combination is missing. p2's v  mapping in [v1], g2's v mapping is [v1,v2]. so p2's v is subset of g2's v

Comment: Sorry , missed some part, edited now with required updates